# Open file with WebStorm from MacOS finder

Tags: macos, webstorm

In OSX El Capitan, I have set WebStorm to be the default application for opening .js files [like so](http://www.imore.com/how-change-default-apps-os-x). This successfully opens WebStorm when opening a .js file via finder, or when cmd-clicking on the file from iterm2.

However, when WebStorm opens, the file I've chosen is not opened within WebStorm. The app simply has the same files I've opened before (whether or not the WebStorm app was running when I opened the file).

Using `open -a /applications/WebStorm.app <filename>` works fine, but it's less convenient than just clicking on the file I want, as I do for file extensions that I've set to open in Eclipse or Sublime.

Is there a way to get WebStorm to open the file I've selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, please follow [IDEA-129532](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129532) for updates

Comment: Not fixed for me in 2020, Webstorm opens but doesn't open the file